# changing number format with php

Tags: php, formatting, numbers, format

I have numbers like these...

```
1.235,45
100,00
5,5678
25.321,10
```

But I need those numbers in the following format:

```
1235.45
100
5.5678
25321.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$number = str_replace('.', '', $number);
$number = str_replace(',', '.', $number);
$number = (float)$number;
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
function cnv($str) {
    $str = str_replace(".", "", $str);
    $str = str_replace(",", ".", $str);
    return (float) $str;
}
```